# Hibernate does not insert the information into the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, persistence

I'm trying to sort of login with JPA and hibernate. The truth is that I'm new to working with hibernate and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I have two entity classes (User and Credential), and I have already mapped them in the persistence.xml file

```
<!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
<persistence-unit name="HibernateSchedule" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>ues.edu.sv.entity.User</class>
    <class>ues.edu.sv.entity.Credential</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/diary?useSSL=false&amp;useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezon=UTC&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

These are the entity classes:

```
package ues.edu.sv.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="User.listAllUsers", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
})
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_user")
private int idUser;

private String name;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;

private String email;

public User(){}

public User(int idUser){
    this.idUser = idUser;
}

public User(String name, String lastName, String email){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public User(int idUser, String name, String lastName, String email){
    this.idUser = idUser;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public int getIdUser() {
    return idUser;
}

public void setIdUser(int idUser) {
    this.idUser = idUser;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}   

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" + "idUser=" + idUser + ", name=" + name + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + '}';
}
   
}
```

This is the Credential class

```
package ues.edu.sv.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Credential.getAllCredentials", query = "SELECT c FROM Credential 
c")
})
@Table(name = "credential")
public class Credential implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_credential")
private int idCredential;

@Column(name = "username")
private String userName;

private String password;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "id_user")
private User user;

public Credential(){}

public Credential(int idCredential){
    this.idCredential = idCredential;
}

public Credential(String userName, String password){
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}

public Credential(String userName, String password, User user){
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.user = user;
}

public Credential(int idCredential,String userName, String password){
    this.idCredential = idCredential;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}

public int getIdCredential() {
    return idCredential;
}

public void setIdCredential(int idCredential) {
    this.idCredential = idCredential;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Credential{" + "idCredential=" + idCredential + ", userName=" + userName + ", password=" + password + ", user=" + user + '}';
}

}
```

I am using a three layer pattern to retrieve the information, so I have a package "ues.edu.sv.dao" where I have two interfaces and two classes that implement them and are defined as ejb

```
package ues.edu.sv.dao;

import java.util.List;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.User;

public interface UserDao {

public List<User> listAllUsers();

public User getUserById(User user);

public void createNewUser(User user);

public void updateUser(User user);

public void deleteUser(User user);
}

package ues.edu.sv.dao;

import java.util.List;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.Credential;

public interface CredentialDao {

public List<Credential> getAllCredentials();

public Credential getCredentialById(Credential credential);

public Credential getCredentialByUserName(Credential credential);

public void createNewCredential(Credential credential);

public void updateCredential(Credential credential);

public void deleteCredential(Credential credential);
}
```

And here are the classes that implement their corresponding interface

```
package ues.edu.sv.dao;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.*;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.User;

@Stateless
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

EntityManagerFactory emf = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernateSchedule");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

@Override
public List<User> listAllUsers() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("User.listAllUsers").getResultList();
}

@Override
public User getUserById(User user) {
    return em.find(User.class, user.getIdUser());
}

@Override
public void createNewUser(User user) {
    em.persist(user);
}

@Override
public void updateUser(User user) {
    em.merge(user);
}

@Override
public void deleteUser(User user) {
    em.remove(em.merge(user));
}

}

package ues.edu.sv.dao;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.Credential;

@Stateless
public class CredentialDaoImpl implements CredentialDao {

EntityManagerFactory emf = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernateSchedule");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

@Override
public List<Credential> getAllCredentials() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Credential.getAllCredentials").getResultList();
}

@Override
public Credential getCredentialById(Credential credential) {
    return em.find(Credential.class, credential.getIdCredential());
}

@Override
public Credential getCredentialByUserName(Credential credential) {
    return em.find(Credential.class, credential.getUserName());
}

@Override
public void createNewCredential(Credential credential) {
    em.persist(credential);
}

@Override
public void updateCredential(Credential credential) {
    em.merge(credential);
}

@Override
public void deleteCredential(Credential credential) {
    em.remove(em.merge(credential));
}

}
```

My understanding is that since I am working in a java enterprise context, there is no need to open a transaction when persisting an object in the database. I am using glassfish by the way.
now to complete the three-layer pattern, I have another package called "ues.edu.sv.service" that injects the above interfaces via CDI

```
package ues.edu.sv.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.Credential;

@Local
public interface CredentialService {

public List<Credential> getAllCredentials();

public Credential getCredentialById(Credential credential);

public Credential getCredentialByUserName(Credential credential);

public void createNewCredential(Credential credential);

public void updateCredential(Credential credential);

public void deleteCredential(Credential credential);
}

package ues.edu.sv.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.User;

@Local
public interface UserService {

public List<User> listAllUsers();

public User getUserById(User user);

public void createNewUser(User user);

public void updateUser(User user);

public void deleteUser(User user);
}
```

and implementation classes

```
package ues.edu.sv.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import ues.edu.sv.dao.CredentialDao;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.Credential;

@Stateless
public class CredentialServiceImpl implements CredentialService{

@Inject
CredentialDao credentialDao;

@Resource
SessionContext context;

@Override
public List<Credential> getAllCredentials() {
    return credentialDao.getAllCredentials();
}

@Override
public Credential getCredentialById(Credential credential) {
    return credentialDao.getCredentialById(credential);
}

@Override
public Credential getCredentialByUserName(Credential credential) {
    return credentialDao.getCredentialByUserName(credential);
}

@Override
public void createNewCredential(Credential credential) {
    credentialDao.createNewCredential(credential);
}

@Override
public void updateCredential(Credential credential) {
    try{
        credentialDao.updateCredential(credential);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        context.setRollbackOnly();
    }
}

@Override
public void deleteCredential(Credential credential) {
    credentialDao.deleteCredential(credential);
}

}

package ues.edu.sv.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import ues.edu.sv.dao.UserDao;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.User;

@Stateless
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

@Inject
UserDao userDao;

@Resource
SessionContext context;

@Override
public List<User> listAllUsers() {
    return userDao.listAllUsers();
}

@Override
public User getUserById(User user) {
    return userDao.getUserById(user);
}

@Override
public void createNewUser(User user) {
    userDao.createNewUser(user);
}

@Override
public void updateUser(User user) {
    try{
        userDao.updateUser(user);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        context.setRollbackOnly();
    }
}

@Override
public void deleteUser(User user) {
    userDao.deleteUser(user);
}

}
```

And finally I have an ejb that connects to the jsf page called "Register.xhtml" and is responsible for retrieving the information that the user enters in the text fields to finally persist the information in the database, I have programmed the relationships so cascading user object can be persisted

```
package ues.edu.sv.beans;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import ues.edu.sv.crypto.Cypher;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.Credential;
import ues.edu.sv.entity.User;
import ues.edu.sv.service.CredentialService;
import ues.edu.sv.service.UserService;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RegisterBean {

@Inject
CredentialService credentialService;

@Inject
UserService userService;

private String name;
private String lastName;
private String email;

private String userName;
private String password;

public RegisterBean() {
}

public void toRegister() {

    User user = new User(name, lastName, email);

    String encriptedPassword = Cypher.encryptPassword(password);
    Credential credential = new Credential(userName, encriptedPassword, user);

    credentialService.createNewCredential(credential);

    try {
        
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("Login.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

And apparently everything is fine, the console does not show me any error, but it does nothing in the database, it does not insert the content into the database :(
This is what appears in the console when everything has been executed...

```
]|#]
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: HibernateSchedule]|#]
HHH000412: Hibernate Core {6.0.0.Alpha4}|#]
HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}|#]
HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)|#]
HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL 
[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/diary? 
useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezon=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true]|#]
HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}|#]
HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false|#]
HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)|#]
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect|#]
HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI 
is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.|#]
HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: 
[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]|#]
```

That is all that appears. Someone who can help me please

Comment: `@Table(name = "\"user\"")` - why is the tablename quoted?

Comment: Because if I left it as "user" it would flag an error and tell me that I was using a SQL reserved word, apparently user cannot be used as a table name. I saw that solution in a forum and it worked! if I persist an individual user it does it correctly